# Finding unique entries with oldest time stamp

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with email addresses and date stamps, I need to find the first email received from each address.

```
df DateTime Email
   10/01/13 a@a.com
   14/02/13 a@a.com
   16/02/13 b@b.com   
   24/07/13 a@a.com
   12/01/12 b@b.com
```

Would something like this work:

```
df.sort(column='DateTime')
new_df = unique(df[df['Email']])
```

Will unique will take the first value of the sorted data frame?
Is there a better way of doing this ? 
Thanks!

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 2):

`DataFrame.drop_duplicates()` defaults to keeping the first observation:

```
DataFrame.drop_duplicates(cols=None, take_last=False, inplace=False)
```

With a sorted `DataFrame` as you suggest, you would end up with the oldest emails only.

See [the documentation for `DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

Let me add that you can indicate on which column to drop duplicates, which would be the email column: `df.drop_duplicates(['Email'])`